# exclude image urls from list of URL

Tags: php, regex

I am collecting list of all urls from web page. My issue is, the list contains all images also which I dont want in my list of URLs.

This script gives me all link from web page.

```
function getUrl($html)
    {
        $regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
        preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
        $urls = $matches[0];
        return $urls;
    }
```

Here is the regex to get image from source code.

`/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpg)\b/`

How can I exclude image from list of extracted URLs?

**UPDATE**

```
$regex = '/(?!.*(?:\.jpe?g|\.gif|\.png)$)\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
        preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
        $urls = $matches[0];
```

why this regex still could not exclue image?

Comment: you can't tell reliably what's an image url from what isn't. urls don't **HAVE** to look like an image, especially if it's something like a direct link to a script which serves an image, e.g. `<a href="script.php?imageID=foo">click here for pic</a>`. you can probably safely assume anything in an `<img src=...>` is an image, but anything else is "good luck at that".

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure your line ends with the extension for an image, then manually remove that line from your list of matches. For example, to ensure a line of code ends with .png or .jpg, match it against:

`/\.(?=(png|jpg)$)/`

So `for` through your list of urls and clone them if they don't match that regex.

Edit: You actually don't even need lookahead, just try to match this:

`\.(png|jpg)$`

and discard matches

Comment: did you mean checking each result, if they match with `\.(png|jpg)$` then discarding it. But I guess it will increase time. If I can update my actual regex. it will be faster. This regex should exclude image link `/(?!.*(?:\.jpe?g|\.gif|\.png)$)\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i` right? but still I am getting link with images